# MS word bullet point indentation changed once after pasting a new text

Tags: microsoft-word

Bullet points keep moving to a different position when a new text is pasted in. The new text is pasted using the paste-attribute "Unformatted".
This is a quite frustrating having to adjust the indentation after each pasting.

Can this be fixed and configured?

MS Word 2016, Windows 10

[image]

Comment: If you click on the clipboard popup below the pasted text, choose the  _Keep Text Only_ option (from the drop-down, the last icon, a clipboard with an A in the lower right corner)

Answer (score 1):

I will wager that you are using the List Paragraph style, what you get by default if you just click the simple bulleted list button on the ribbon. You then attempted to do what is called "Direct Format" the item in your list by moving the indentation level back to zero, a.k.a. left margin.

The bottom-line is, when done that way, your direct formatting won't stick, especially when pasting in new text. You need to create your own bulleted list style.

The resource to read on "[How to control bulleted lists](https://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html)" is from a website created by a woman named Shauna Kelly, who has since passed away. Her site is maintained by a group of dedicated volunteers. It's a solid resource, no gimmicks or advertising. If you are still skittish about the link I've provided, then just do a web search on **ShaunaKelly.com**.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem with MS 2013.
I found another solution to this problem without having to change the paragraph style:

1. Go to

   > Word options -> Advanced Options -> Cut, copy and paste
2. Untick the options "copy-paste with spaces management" and save the configuration
3. Paste your text in your bullet list with Merge Formatting.

This should work.
I give it here, because this solution may help someone else.

Disclaimer:
I've a french version of MS Word, so maybe I've badly translated some terms.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the simplest way to deal with this is to open a new window in Word, paste the text into it, and then copy or cut the text from the 'dummy' Word document and paste it into the actual target document.

If you use this method, you may need to ensure that 'smart paragraph selection' does not include the trailing return character, which will cause the bullet mark to be lost. I do this by appending a couple of spaces to the copied text, but not including them when I copy it into the target document.